# WAMP: phpmyAdmin gives access denied after I create password using cmd.exe

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi I'm pretty new to the WAMP scene, I've just downloaded WAMP from:
http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

And got it installed with ease. I've set up a password to MySQL using cmd.exe on Windows (7, 64-bit) using the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password "newpassword"
```

Now when I click the WAMPSERVER icon on my system tray, go to phpmyAdmin I get hit with an Access denied page which states:

MySQL said:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

If anyone can help me out that would be magnificent, I pretty much have no knowledge about servers and such, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should check the host, username
>   and password in your configuration and
>   make sure that they correspond to the
>   information given by the administrator
>   of the MySQL server.

Find your `config.inc.php` file under the phpMyAdmin installation directory and update the line that looks like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

... to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'newpassword';
```